# Setting Alpha level on view doesn't work

Tags: android

I am trying to set the alpha level of a view.
I am reading the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

and it seems as if it should be possible even on android 2.1 which I am developing for (as I cant see it saying otherwise) but when I add it to my view

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20sp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
   android:alpha="0.9"></View>
```

I get an error saying:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package
>   'android'

How do I set the alpha level of a view?

Comment: Well this is odd, you are doing it excactly as stated by the documentation. Could you try to use an integer value between 0 -255, so no decimals? [Resource Document](http://android.ubiwireless.com/Documentation.doc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can set the alpha with the background properties like this way

```
android:background="#50ffffff"
```

here the first 50 value is set the alpha value

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why it's the other way that's documented?

Comment: Are running this on a tablet? Because that is only available since api version 11.

Comment: That's why then! the documentation I was reading didn't seem to specify that.

Comment: Finally an answer that really made it work! Before I always found to use alpha property which did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

On which android version are you running this?

setAlpha is only available on api level 11. You might try some other way to do this if you want to do this in previous versions. Probably using a semi-transparent background could do it.